# Android how to manage project name and logo and application icon for different clients

Tags: android, android-resources, android-flavors

As per need i need to manage one project for different clients in which i usually need to change application icon, app name and client logo. what is the efficient way to handle this??

I have read about properties file in the Android but that does provide option to change application icon and name.. it there any why to handle this.

Comment: Flavors are your friend in these kind of situations. Each client has his own flavor of the project, and build.gradle / AndroidManifest.xml in which you define the things you need such as the icon and the packagename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you will to have use flavour in your project, if you are using Android studio add the following code in your build.gradle file.

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        applicationId "com.app.client1"
    }
    flavor2 {
        applicationId "com.app.client2"
    }
}
```

Then create directory structure like

```
flavor1>res>drawable-XXX>ic_launcher.png (app icon for client1)
flavor2>res>drawable-XXX>ic_launcher.png (app icon for client2)
```

For more you can refer to this blog http://www.pcsalt.com/android/product-flavors-android/

Answer (score 1):

You can create Multiple flavor for multiple vendors like this:

Here is a syntax for gradle

```
productFlavors {
  flavor1 {
    packageName 'com.android.studio.test.foobar'
  }
}
```

You can also put variable to make changes in app according to flavor